# javascript how to dynamically append child dicts to a parent dict

Tags: javascript, typescript, dictionary, javascript-objects

I have a Javascript object like so:

```
const childDict = {
  address: {
    zip: "GGHG654",
    city: "Morocco",
    number: 40
  }
}
```

I want to add this to another parent dictionary dynamically in a loop like so:

```
let parentDict = {}

for(let i = 0 ; i < 3; i++){
  parentDict["place" + i] = childDict
}
```

So in the end I end up with one dict like so:

```
{
  place0: {
    address: {
      zip: "GGHG654",
      city: "Morocco",
      number: 40
    }
  },
  place1: {
    address: {
      zip: "GGHG654",
      city: "Morocco",
      number: 40
    }
  }
}
```

The for loop is however giving me a compile error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.
```

Comment: What issue are you having with current code?

Comment: @palaѕн parentDict["place" + i] is giving a compile error. I edited the question to include the error.

Comment: loop only to the length of childDict items

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add appropriate interface to the parent dictionary as typescript automatically assigns the type based on the initial value, which does not have any keys

```
interface IParentDict {
    [key: string]: any; // possibly change any to the typeof child dict
}
const parentDict: IParentDict = {};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let parentDict = {}
```

This has no type set explicitly which is causing this issue. Try to provide a `any` type like:

```
let parentDict:any = {}
```

Or, to be more accurate:

```
let parentDict:{[key: string]: object} = {}
```

Answer (score 0):

try it like this

`let parentDict: any = {};`

another option could be specifying type in a more correct way, like

`let parentDict: {[key: string]: any} = {};`

Another hacky way is

```
let parentDict = {}

for(let i = 0 ; i < 3; i++){
    (parentDict as any)["place" + i] = childDict
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution kind of works, you just need to specify the type of parentDict as any type. 
Did you try doing a console.log(parentDict) after the for loop